# How to remove the placeholder from the material design outlined textfield

Tags: html, forms, material-design

I am trying to create a simple form using material design component and it doesn't work properly placeholder doesn't removed when i starts entering the details how can i do this and i also tried using the filled also but on that also i am not able to remove the background placeholder here is my tried code and i have added all the material library required for this https://material.io/develop/web/docs/getting-started

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      #get-started {
        background-color: #9e0b0f;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 0;
        font-family: "NewsGothicBold", san-serif !important;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        margin: auto;
        display: block;
        padding: 10px 22px 5px 25px;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: normal;
        margin-top: 20px;
      }

      .forms {
        font-family: "NewsGothicBold", san-serf;
        width: 390px;
        margin: 20px auto 0;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        padding: 0 0 40px;
        border-radius: 8px;
        color: #555;
        background-color: #fff;
      }

      .username,
      .password {
        display: flex;
        margin: 20px auto;
        width: 300px;
      }
      .mdc-text-field {
        width: 350px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-left: 20px;
      }
      .mdc-select {
        width: 350px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-left: 20px;
      }

      @media (max-width: 450px) {
        .forms {
          font-family: "NewsGothicBold", san-serf;
          width: 330px;
          margin-top: 20px !important;
          margin: 0 auto;
          box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          padding: 0 0 40px;
          border-radius: 8px;
          color: #555;
          background-color: #fff;
        }
        .mdc-text-field {
          width: 290px;
          margin-top: 20px;
          margin-left: 20px;
        }
        .mdc-select {
          width: 290px;
          margin-top: 20px;
          margin-left: 20px;
        }
      }
      
              </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="forms">
      <form>
        <label class="mdc-text-field mdc-text-field--outlined">
          <span class="mdc-notched-outline">
            <span class="mdc-notched-outline__leading"></span>
            <span class="mdc-notched-outline__notch">
              <span class="mdc-floating-label" id="my-label-id">Your Name</span>
            </span>
            <span class="mdc-notched-outline__trailing"></span>
          </span>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="mdc-text-field__input"
            aria-labelledby="my-label-id"
          />
        </label>
        <label class="mdc-text-field mdc-text-field--outlined">
          <span class="mdc-notched-outline">
            <span class="mdc-notched-outline__leading"></span>
            <span class="mdc-notched-outline__notch">
              <span class="mdc-floating-label" id="my-label-id"
                >Your EMAIL</span
              >
            </span>
            <span class="mdc-notched-outline__trailing"></span>
          </span>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="mdc-text-field__input"
            aria-labelledby="my-label-id"
          />
        </label>

        <button class="mdc-button mdc-button--raised mt-10" id="get-started">
          <div class="mdc-button__ripple"></div>
          <span class="mdc-button__label">DOWNLOAD YOUR GUIDE</span>
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hello**, I tried to use your code and it looks like the input is at the front and the placeholder your saying is at the back. If you still don't understand me. Remove the class on the input like this:

```
<input
   type="text"
   //remove the class
   aria-labelledby="my-label-id"
 />
```

[image]

so I think you have to use other form design. Or like this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
    />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      #get-started {
        background-color: #9e0b0f;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 0;
        font-family: "NewsGothicBold", san-serif !important;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        margin: auto;
        display: block;
        padding: 10px 22px 5px 25px;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: normal;
        margin-top: 20px;
      }

      .forms {
        font-family: "NewsGothicBold", san-serf;
        width: 390px;
        margin: 20px auto 0;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        padding: 0 0 40px;
        border-radius: 8px;
        color: #555;
        background-color: #fff;
      }
      input[type="text"] {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 20px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 46px;
        border: 1px solid rgb(172, 172, 172);
        border-radius: 4px;
      }
      .mdc-text-field--outlined {
        height: 56px;
        overflow: visible;
      }

      .username,
      .password {
        display: flex;
        margin: 20px auto;
        width: 300px;
      }
      .mdc-text-field {
        width: 350px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-left: 20px;
      }
      .mdc-select {
        width: 350px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-left: 20px;
      }

      @media (max-width: 450px) {
        .forms {
          font-family: "NewsGothicBold", san-serf;
          width: 330px;
          margin-top: 20px !important;
          margin: 0 auto;
          box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          padding: 0 0 40px;
          border-radius: 8px;
          color: #555;
          background-color: #fff;
        }
        .mdc-text-field {
          width: 290px;
          margin-top: 20px;
          margin-left: 20px;
        }
        .mdc-select {
          width: 290px;
          margin-top: 20px;
          margin-left: 20px;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="forms">
      <form>
        <label class="mdc-text-field mdc-text-field--outlined">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Your Name"
            aria-labelledby="my-label-id"
          />
        </label>
        <label class="mdc-text-field mdc-text-field--outlined">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Your Name"
            aria-labelledby="my-label-id"
          />
        </label>

        <button class="mdc-button mdc-button--raised mt-10" id="get-started">
          <div class="mdc-button__ripple"></div>
          <span class="mdc-button__label">DOWNLOAD YOUR GUIDE</span>
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

let me know if I helped, Good Luck. Take Care!!!